# Enable/Disable CodeQL code scanning for a repo using Github Rest API

Tags: github, codeql

Is it possible to enable/disable CodeQL code scanning for a repo using Github Rest API in any of the Github accounts?(Personal accounts/ Organization accounts /Enterprise accounts)

https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/code-scanning?apiVersion=2022-11-28#about-code-scanning

Please refer to this document.I tried to automate enable/disable codeql for a repo using github rest api.Couldnt find any solution in this documentation.

Comment: Looks like GitHub just added exactly (?) what you were asking for, see my updated answer for the links to the GitHub blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** GitHub now added new APIs to enable the code scanning default setup [at organization level](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-03-20-enable-code-scanning-default-setup-with-codeql-at-the-organization-level-public-beta/) and for [single repositories](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-03-21-code-scanning-api-to-enable-default-setup-with-codeql-on-a-repository/). But keep in mind that the default setup does not work for all programming languages supported by CodeQL at the moment.

---

The API only seems to provide endpoints for getting code scanning results at the moment. Also, [until recently](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-01-09-code-scanning-can-be-set-up-more-easily-without-committing-a-workflow-file-to-the-repository/) you always had to include configuration files in your repository to set up CodeQL code scanning. And depending on what languages you want to scan you might still need configuration files, see the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/configuring-code-scanning-for-a-repository#configuring-code-scanning-automatically).

However, if you have already set up CodeQL code scanning manually you could maybe use the REST API endpoints for [disabling](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#disable-a-workflow) and [enabling](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#enable-a-workflow) the already existing code scanning workflow.

Disabling CodeQL code scanning (through the REST API) seems like a rather uncommon use case. Could you explain your use case a bit more in detail? Maybe there are better ways to solve this, for example you can customize which [severities cause a pull request check failure](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/customizing-code-scanning#defining-the-severities-causing-pull-request-check-failure).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a way to disable them, but you can just upload an empty codeql.yml in .github/workflows/codeql.yml file, and github will stop codeql tests.
Feel free to try it.